# updating google spreadsheet B from google spreadsheet A

Tags: google-apps-script

Using a script on spreadsheet A I am trying to update a newly created spreadheet B. The end purpose is to have a CRM sheet (spreadsheet A) from which I can generate invoices (spreadsheet B).

In the script below, all works until the line "sh_Invoice.getRange(5,12).setValue("test");".
When debugging I can see the objects coming alive, but the setValue() is just not working. I just a blank copy of the copied spreadheet.
The custom function calls getCustomerData() and copyFileInFolder work fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

```html
function createNewInvoice () {
  // gets handle on active sheet
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // check if active sheet is CRM
  if (sh.getName() != "CRM") {
    showError(messageData.DialogTitle, messageData.Error0);
    return;
  }
  // build customer json table from active row in sheet
  var customer = getCustomerData(sh);
  // copy invoice template
  var f_Invoice = copyFileInFolder(configData.IdInvoiceTmpl);
  var ss_Invoice = SpreadsheetApp.openById(f_Invoice.getId());
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss_Invoice);
  ss_Invoice.rename("Factuur 2015-" + configData.invoiceNumber + " (" + customer.name + ")");
  // fill in some data in the new sheet
  var sh_Invoice = ss_Invoice.setActiveSheet(ss_Invoice.getSheets()[0]);
  sh_Invoice.getRange(5,12).setValue("test");
  // set CRM spreadsheet back to active
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your issue, but your code seems to work for me.  For debugging purposes, try breaking up the chain and create a Range called `sh_Invoice_cell` and then set the value on the next line.  See if the cell is defined.  So... `sh_Invoice_cell = sh_Invoice.getRange(5,2);` and then
    `sh_Invoice_cell.setValue("test");`

Comment: I have tried it with breaking up the chain in smaller pieces as you suggest, but it still doesnot set a value in the new spreadsheet's first sheet.

Comment: what does Logger.log(sh_Invoice_cell) log into the console?

Comment: I think the problem is your `copyFileInFolder` function.  Can you post it?

Comment: @Sandy Good: This  is the code for copyFileInFolder + another function that is used.

function getFolderForFile(file) {
 var folderIt = file.getParents();
  if (folderIt.hasNext()) {
    return (folderIt.next());
  }
}
/**
creates a copy of the requested file (fileId) in the same folder
*/
function copyFileInFolder(fileId) {
  // get handle on file
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  // get handle on this files folder
  var folder = getFolderForFile(file);
  // make a copy of the file in the same folder
  var newFile = file.makeCopy("a copy", folder);

  return newFile;
}
'code'

Comment: @zbnrg: the statement Logger.log(sh_Invoice_cell.getValue() just displays the timestamp, but not the expected text "test"